# Converting byte array to image

Tags: c#, image, byte, server, arrays

We are using Flash to send an image to the servers and upload an image. The way we're trying to do this is by sending the bytes to the server through a parameter and then converting the bytes to an image.

http://i.gyazo.com/fb8225af80ef465b0262d97f63bd54b2.png

In the image the object is sending a few different bits of information. I'm not sure if I am supposed to just receive one bit of information instead of the entire object.

So far I have the post request

```
string byteArray = Request["bytes"];
```

Then I am trying to convert it to an image

```
string file_name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

//byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(byteArray);

Derio.App.Model.Helper.ByteArrayToFile(file_name, Derio.App.Model.Helper.GetBytes(byteArray));
```

My helper method looks like -

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToFile(string _FileName, byte[] _ByteArray)
    {
        try
        {
            // Open file for reading
            System.IO.FileStream _FileStream =
               new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create,
                                        System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
            // Writes a block of bytes to this stream using data from
            // a byte array.
            _FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 0, _ByteArray.Length);

            // close file stream
            _FileStream.Close();

            return "true";
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            // Error
            return "Exception caught in process:" +     _Exception.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

We've multiple different methods such as trying to convert it from Base64String to an image.

I can't for the life of me though figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well you haven't told us what the problem is, to start with. (I'm not at all keen on the way you're "handling" exceptions in `ByteArrayToFile`, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Have you tried `Image.FromStream(memory_stream);` ?

Comment: Holy exception handler, Batman! `return "true";`?! For real?

Comment: I was only returning it like that so I could return the error to the device, wasn't a permanent placement

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? And at which line? Can you update your question with those information, please?

Comment: Check the number of bytes in the input file and find out where in the code the number of bytes is changing.  the number of bytes at the end of the code should be exactly the same a the original file.  If the number of bytes is different then you have an error.  the Filestream MUST MUST use UTF8 encoding. So add stream reader :             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_FileStream, Encoding.UTF8);  Also you are reading a file, but opening the file as WRITE.

Comment: Since the image is binary data which is usually encoded as a base 64 string for HTTP, you probably have to decode `Request["bytes"]` from base 64 to a `byte[]`. Afterwards you can use `File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)` to store the `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try this:

```
string file_name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string byteArray = Request["bytes"];
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(byteArray);
IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file_name, imageBytes);
```

Comment: I get the error - System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)\r\n   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)\r\n   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)

Comment: This is the _stacktrace_ of the error/exception, i.e. _where_ the exception happend. But what is the exception type and message?

Comment: The message is: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Comment: What does `byteArray` look like? Can you post the first few characters of it here? Also what happens when you exchange line 3 in my code sample with  `byte[] imageBytes = Derio.App.Model.Helper.GetBytes(byteArray)`?

Comment: It's successfully uploaded, but it's not an image, it's "Windows photo viewer can't open this picture, if I open it in notepad, it has the text "ÿØÿà", also I posted a picture of what byteArray is

Comment: You posted a picture of the _structure_ of `Request["bytes"]` but we don't know what the actual _content_ looks like which you are storing in `byteArray`. I'm asking because I suspect there's rubbish in there. Probably the client converts the binary image data to a `char[]`, creates a `string` from that and passes that to the request instead of using `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`.